# Save pdf with plot and latex

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I want to save my plot with font from Latex, but I have error:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

I initialize Latex in pyplot by:

```
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
```

And save pdf by:

```
fig.savefig('myplot.pdf', transparent=True)
```

Saving all to png works, only pdf failed. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you have the [PDF backend installed and active](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend)?

Comment: Saving to png or pdf with disable TeX works

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] including the complete error traceback. Otherwise this question is not useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save matplotlib pyplot while using tex as pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48465471/save-matplotlib-pyplot-while-using-tex-as-pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Try importing Pdfpages from matplotlib and implement as following:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

    fig = plt.figure()
    pdf = PdfPages('foo.pdf')
    pdf.savefig(fig)

    pdf.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution from [here](https://timodenk.com/blog/exporting-matplotlib-plots-to-latex/) worked.

> Adjust your matplotlib script by adding the following lines after
> import matplotlib:

```
matplotlib.use("pgf")
matplotlib.rcParams.update({
    "pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",
    'font.family': 'serif',
    'text.usetex': True,
    'pgf.rcfonts': False,
})
```