# Save matplotlib pyplot while using tex as pdf

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am making a plot using matplotlib. The graph is correctly displayed in jupyter notebook, but I am not able to save it as a pdf. Saving as a png works fine, but this is regrettably not an option for me.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

values= [[0,   -1.055], [2.5, -1.798], [6.5, -1.662], [9,   -1.274],
        [10,  -0.939], [11,  -0.527], [12,  -0.338], [15,   0.345],
        [17,  -0.146], [19,  -1.526], [19,  -1.395], [21,  -2.454]]

values= np.array(values)

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(9,6.5))

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')

plt.scatter(values[:,0], values[:,1])
plt.show()

pdf = PdfPages('test.pdf')
pdf.savefig(fig)
pdf.close()
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Complete error dump: https://pastebin.com/rFTr3ehU

I am running python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] and matplotlib version 2.1.0.

Comment: did you try just using `fig.savefig('test.pdf')` rather than using `PdfPages`?

Comment: Using python 2.7 (64bit) and matplotlib 2.1.2 the code runs fine in a jupyter notebook. Could there be a problem with the anaconda distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this helps?

There was this Fix TypeError:
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/9292/commits/37ad476aec62ce58f95c91e6aabd55cfc3b5af25

and the same problem was adressed here:
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9671

Either you get the fixed version or downgrade to:  Matplot 2.0.2